# Finding min element of array in MIPS

Tags: mips

I have seen that this question was already asked, but I'm trying to find why this logic is not working. I have tried this code, translating it to C++ and it is working fine. But here it is printing the last element of the array. Help?

```
   .data

    Array:      .word 500 100 250 150

    Len:        .word 4

    Sum:        .word 0

    Average:    .word 0

    NewLine:    .asciiz "\n"

    Min:        .word 9999

    Max:        .word -9999

    .text

        la $t0, Array       # Base address
        li $t1, 0           # i = 0
        lw $t2, Len         # $t2 = Len
        li $t3, 0           # Sum = 0
        li $t5, 0           # Average = 0 
        la $t6, NewLine  
        lw $t7, Min         # $t7 = min
        lw $t8, Max         # $t8 = max

        while:
            lw   $t4, ($t0)              # Array[i]
            add  $t3, $t3, $t4           # sum += Array[i]

            blt  $t4, $t7, else          # If first element is < 9999, go to else  
            else: move $t7, $t4          # Min = Array[i]

            add  $t1, $t1, 1             # Increment index by 1
            add  $t0, $t0, 4             # Go to next array element

            blt  $t1, $t2, while         # Do this cycle till i < $t2 (length)


            sw   $t3, Sum                

            div  $t5, $t3, $t2           # Calculate avg.
            sw   $t5, Average           

            # Print sum
            li   $v0, 1
            move $a0, $t3
            syscall

            # Print new line
            li   $v0, 4
            move $a0, $t6
            syscall

            # Print average
            li $v0, 1
            move $a0, $t5
            syscall

            # Print new line
            li   $v0, 4
            move $a0, $t6
            syscall

            # Print min element
            li $v0, 1
            move $a0, $t7
            syscall
```

Answer (score 1):

Compiler reads the code from up to down, let's look at calculating the minimum part of your code:

```
blt  $t4, $t7, else          # If first element is < 9999, go to else  
else: move $t7, $t4          # Min = Array[i]
```

In the first line, it branches to **else** if $t4 < $t7. Looks fine for this situaton but if $t4 < $t7 it skips branching, then pass to the next line which is your **else**. So, that blz is uselles here because it will go the else line anyway so this code will always print the last element of your array.

But if you change your code like:

```
 blt  $t7, $t4, else          # If first element is < 9999, go to else  
     move $t7, $t4          # Min = Array[i]
else:
...
```

It will skip "move $t7, $t4 line" if $t7 > $t4, so it will give you what you want.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand what do you achieve with the code(I am beginner at MIPS). If I use blt $t7, $t4, else , then what am I supposed to write in "else" label? I translate my code like this:
If 500 < 9999 then min is 500,
If 100 < 500 then min is 100,
and when 250 < 100 then the branching does not go to else and min remains 100. I don't see the problem here in this statement?

Comment: Do not think "else" like "else" in C (or any other) language. It's just a label, you can rename it "myelse" and nothing will be changed.

When you convert your code to C, it's like:

if( t4< t7)
{
goto xxxx;
}
xxxx:
t4=t7;

So it will compile t4=t7 anyway.

Comment: Yes, but this isn't storing $t4(the smallest element) in $t7.

Comment: I guess you see 64 there and that confuses you. Registers holds hexadecimal values. Minimum element is 100, when you convert it to hexadecimal it becomes 64. But when you print it to screen, you can see it's 100.